# Angular $scope values set in reverse order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been working on Angular for one month now. I have been struggling with scoping and keeping state between views.

I don't know how to debug in angular, so I use the console to track the values of the scope when a view is loaded.

This is one of my controllers:

```
.controller('LegDetailCtrl',function($scope,$stateParams, LegService,ControllerService){
    $scope.reservation = ControllerService.getReservation();
    LegService.getLeg($stateParams.legId).then(function(data){
        ControllerService.setLeg(data.data);
        $scope.leg = data.data;
        console.log('Check leg',angular.toJson($scope.leg));
    });

    $scope.seats = LegService.getSeats();
    $scope.pax = LegService.getPax();
    $scope.user = ControllerService.getUser();
    $scope.reservation.leg = $scope.leg;
    $scope.reservation.client = $scope.user;
    $scope.reservation.pax = $scope.pax;
    console.log('Check scope leg', angular.toJson($scope.leg));
})
```

As I understand, in JS the execution is made in order from top to bottom (not sure of this). I think this way, I am processing and then setting the $scope.leg value, then I use it to feed the $scope.reservation object.

To me, the correct console output would be:

```
log Check leg, {aJsonObject}
log Check scope leg, {anotherJsonObject}
```

But what I get is this:

```
log Check scope leg,
log Check leg, {aJsonObject}
```

So, it looks like it sets all the values to the scope and then, executes the LegService.getLeg() method.

How do I make this to run in the correct order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to control the order of aync stuff you can chain your promises. Looks like you have this case here, but really hard to tell. Fiddle?

Comment: @marko it is exactly that. I have tried cbass's solution, but it is not processing the data to set the leg value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using chrome there's a great debugging tool for AngularJS apps called [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)
.

To solve your problem you can chain your promises like below.

```
function LegDetailCtrl($stateParams, LegService, ControllerService){
    var vm=this;
    vm.reservation=ControllerService.getReservation();

    LegService
        .getLeg($stateParams.legId)
        .then(function(data){
            ControllerService.setLeg(data.data);
            vm.leg=data.data;
            return data.data;
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            var user=ControllerService.getUser();
            var pax=LegService.getPax();
            var seats=LegService.getSeats();

            vm.seats=seats
            vm.pax=pax
            vm.user=user
            vm.reservation.leg=vm.leg;
            vm.reservation.client=user
            vm.reservation.pax=pax
        });
}
LegDetailCtrl.$inject=['$stateParams', 'LegService', 'ControllerService'];

angular
    .module('yourModule')
    .controller('LegDetailCtrl', LegDetailCtrl)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. The only problem is that apparently, the ControllerService.setLeg(data.data) is not processing. It is setting the $scope.leg with the raw data from the rest api of LegService

Comment: Yes, it was processing the data correctly before chaining the promises

Comment: Greetings. I have learned that in order to execute a call after another is executed, the promises must be nested one inside of other. The ControllerService.setLeg() method, makes three different calls to the rest api, but they are made all at the same time. Nesting the promises solved my issue. I will be posting the solution later. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thats correct. Didnt know that one returned a promise. You might want add an extra then mehtod and only have the ControllerService.setLeg() in the first. Then(function() { return ControllerService.setLeg()}).then(doSomeOtherStuff)

Answer (score 1):

The `.then(` in the following line

```
LegService.getLeg($stateParams.legId).then(function(data){
```

is an asynchonous call to the function inside the then-block (which contains the "Check leg")

The execution is deferred till the event loop of javascript is empty (javascript is only single threaded).
That means that the code of the main function is executed first (result is "Check scope leg")
and after that the async call inside the then-block is executed ("Check leg")

Answer (score 0):

If you ran this code outside of the browser, you'd find that the `console.log` call within the callback you passed to `then` is never called at all. That is because the callback is not called until the promise returned by `getLeg` is resolved, and that won't happen until the next angular `$digest` cycle.